# Query for changing the id to name from two different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table C which contains id of table A and also id of table B. How can I select all the unique rows and change the ids into corresponding names from table A and B.

```
  table contain IDs    Table A           Table B
  ---------------      ---------------   ---------------
  A_id   |  B_id      A_id   |  Name      B_id   |  Name
  ---------------      ---------------   ---------------
  1      |    2        1      |    AA      1      |    a
  1      |    4        2      |    BB      2      |    b
  3      |    2        3      |    CC      3      |    c
  3      |    1        4      |    DD      4      |    d
  3      |    1
```

The result must be

```
 ---------------   
  A_Name |  B_Name
  --------------
  AA      |    b 
  AA      |    d 
  CC      |    b 
  CC      |    a
```

Many Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is
 
[INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp):***The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables*.** and 
[DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp):***The DISTINCT keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.***

```
select distinct a.name,b.name 
from c 
inner join b using(b_id) 
inner join a using(a_id)
```

Go through [PostgreSQL - JOINS](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_joins.htm) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to join across all three tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.name, B.name
FROM A 
INNER JOIN C
ON A.A_id = C.A_id
INNER JOIN B
ON B.B_id = C.B_id
```

The 'DISTINCT' keyword eliminates duplicates (specifically, the last two rows in Table C).

This query works for me with your sample data.